# How to register component for multiple level

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

I try to register the Components by using Autofac in MVC5 C#.
Let me provide a brief description:
I have registered the following components

```
builder.RegisterType<OrderItemRepo>().As<IOrderItemRepo>();
builder.RegisterType<OrderRepo>().As<IOrderRepo>();
builder.RegisterType<OrderService>().As<IOrderService>()

builder.RegisterType<POItemRepo>().As<IPOItemRepo>();
builder.RegisterType<POrderRepo>().As<IPOrderRepo>();
builder.RegisterType<POService>().As<IPOService>()
```

the implement `OrderService` uses `DI` `IOrderRepo` and `IOrderItemRepo`

the same pattern, the implement `POService` uses `DI` `IPOrderRepo` and `IPOItemRepo`

these interfaces `IPOService` and `IOrderService` both inherate `IBaseRepo`

with `IBaseRepo` is:

```
public interface IBaseRepo{}
```

in MVC Controller in constructor,

```
public DefaultController(IBaseRepo states)
{
    _states = states;
}
```

I would like to see if there is way to register the IBaseRepo with some parameter as string,
the idea is, I will pass 1 parameter `processName=Order` or `processName=POrder` on the URL.

the `Controller` will find the `DI` from IBaseRepo like:

if `processName=Order` >> it will be `IOrderService`

if `processName=POrder` >> it will be `IPOService`

I read some sample from [Named and Keyed Services] (https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#resolving-with-attributes) but I don't still figure out how to do.

I would like to appreciate if everyone can give me some advices or sample case.
Thank you in advance.

p/s: I'm sorry if my English is not good.

Thomas.

Comment: Did you check this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986395/autofac-named-registration-constructor-injection/23992803

Comment: hi @kosist, 
I already read it, but it's not similar with my situation.
the scenario from there is, multiple class implements 1 interface.
and mine is, multiple interfaces `IPOService ` , `IPOService`  inherate 1 interface  `IBaseRepo `

Comment: OK, I see. But what you are trying to reach should be solved by implementing base controller and two its childs. And based on the parameter in the request string you would redirect action to proper controller. Which would already have proper interface injected into the controller constructor.

Comment: yes, exactly , @kosist.
Actually, I will have many interfaces but I just use 2 interfaces to describe my issue.

Comment: If I understand correctly your specific interfaces define specific methods for those repositories and differ from each other. So then anyway it is better to separate into different controllers - because otherwise you'll end up with the situation when one controller refers to various repositories, which I guess is not good from architecture point of view.

Comment: This is generally not a good idea - if you can't treat all `IBaseRepo` equally, you're violating Liskov substitution principle. [There's an FAQ about this in the Autofac doc.](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)